# Keyboard not opening when tapped

Tags: ios, swift

I have textfields inside a tableview. Whenever a textfield is tapped another row appears with a textfield. But keyboard is not opening when textfield is tapped. It is creating a textfield but keyboard isn't opening up. Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var contactPersonsTableView: UITableView!
var contactPersons = [String]()
var index = 0
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return contactPersons.count + 1

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "contactPersonCell", for: indexPath) as! ContactPersonTableViewCell
    cell.contactPerson.delegate = self
    cell.contactPerson.tag = indexPath.row
    return cell
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
index = textField.tag
textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    if(textField.text!.isEmpty)
    {
        contactPersons.insert("", at: index)
        contactPersonsTableView.reloadData()

    }

}
```

Comment: simulator or device? is the focused cursor blinking?

Comment: Calling `textField.becomeFirstResponder()` inside `textFieldDidBeginEditing` make no sense. `textFieldDidBeginEditing` will only be called when `textField` is already the first responder.

Comment: What exactly does `hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround` do?

Comment: Why are you adding a new cell in textFieldDidBeginEditing?

Comment: Both simulator and device don't work

Comment: hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround hides the keyboard when tapped on the screen

Comment: I added textField.becomeFirstResponder when keyboard wasn't opening up then I tried adding this that it might work but didn't

Comment: I am adding a new cell because I need a new textField created every time user taps empty textField

Comment: This because tableViewCell is selection trigged before the texView or textfield. [This article may help you](https://link.medium.com/qb2f4abhPW)